# Rails include javascripts assets folder recursively

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I understand how to add one javascript file to rails assets pipeline. Just add

```
//= require filename
```

to application.js

But how can I include many javscripts files under one folder

```
vendor/assets/javascripts/<js_library>
```

Or I have to list them all explicitly ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
//= require_tree .
```

will require everything in the current directory of your application.js

```
//= require_tree ./js_library
```

will require everything in the `js_library` subdirectory if it is under app/assets/javascripts

If you are are trying to load javascripts under vendor/assets/javascripts, try:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/js_library
```

Comment: I got this error message `require_tree argument must be a relative path` when I added `//= require_tree js_library`

Comment: Hmm - didn't realize you have to make it relative. Updated answer.

Comment: I got this message `require_tree argument must be a directory` after I updated to `//= require_tree ./js_library` something i am missing?

Comment: Can you confirm the directory has files? Can you also confirm there are no empty directories within that directory? This might cause problems.

Comment: Yes I confirmed. My `js_library` is located under `vendor/assets/javascripts/`. Might it be a problem ? It seems yes.  I moved js_library from `vendor/assets/javascripts/` to `app/assets/javascripts`. You answer works perfectly!

Comment: Ah. Fixed - you have to change it again for vendor assets.

Comment: for `rails 4` app, if try to add js folder under lib, should be //= require_tree ../../../lib/assets/javascripts/js_library