# Error='ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:Couldn't find Game with 'id'=worker-javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm running into this error ONLY when the app is running in production...

```
method=GET path=/games/worker-javascript.js format=js controller=games action=show status=500 
Error='ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:Couldn't find Game with 'id'=worker-javascript'
```

The `worker-javascript` shown in the error is a javascript file in one of the 3rd part library directories in my vendor directory. `Game` is one of my models. Since one of the big differences between my development environment and my production environment is compiled assets, I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I'm precompiling my assets, but I'm too new to Rails to see anything obviously wrong. Here's the manifest file I'm using for the page that's throwing the error...

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require browser_details
//= require turbolinks
//= require ace
```

The `worker-javascript.js` file is a file in the `/vendor/assets/javascripts/ace/` directory, which I'm including with `//= require ace`.

Any ideas why this could be happening? Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1):

You should link the file using

```
//= require ace/worker-javascript
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

EDIT: You cannot just include the whole folder ace by the line you wrote, you will need to do something on these lines
[Rails include javascripts assets folder recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226156/rails-include-javascripts-assets-folder-recursively)

PS: Are you trying to include the js somewhere else too? like using a inline javascript_include_tag worker-javascript or something?

Comment: Thanks, Ankur. I updated my manifest to use the `//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/ace`, but it doesn't fix the problem. My production logs still show `method=GET path=/games/worker-javascript.js format=js controller=games action=show status=500 
Error='ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:Couldn't find Game with 'id'=worker-javascript'`. Question, if `//= require ace` is wrong, why does it work in development? Also, any other ideas?

Comment: Can you please include the application.rb,development.rb and production.rb configs? It maybe a problem of incorrectly configured asset pipeline.

Or the problem then must lie in the place where you are actually trying to link the js file. Perhaps a script tag that says src="worker-javascript.js" or something, because it is not trying to find the javascript using the asset pipeline but instead trying to find it in the same directory itself. We do need more code sample to figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ankur. I'm not trying to directly link to that file anywhere (i.e. I don't have src="worker-javascript.js" anywhere in my code) and it doesn't seem like the problem is that my app is not trying to find the javascript using the asset pipeline either. To me, the problem stems from the fact that my app is making a request for a Game object, with the id "worker-javascript.js" (i.e. method=GET path=/games/worker-javascript.js). What could be causing that? If you still think I need to post my environment files, please let me know.

Comment: Did you precompile the assets?